# Qt - statically compiled exe refers shared lib

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, qt, logic

My static compilation in Qt worked fine upto this week. I reinstalled the qt, and recompiled the static version. The headache started after this. Now, even though I compiled using tatic version. The resulting exe requires the Qt libs. I checked the exe with "dependency Walker". It showed that the required dll's path are pointing towards the dynamic/shared libs path.  Here are my settings

```
Environment:
QTDYNDIR : D:\tempinstallationfolder\Qt\dynamic
QTSTADIR : D:\tempinstallationfolder\Qt\static
Path : %QTDYNDIR%\bin;%QTDYNDIR%\qt\bin;%QTDYNDIR%\mingw\bin;
       %QTSTADIR%\bin;%QTSTADIR%\qt\bin;%QTSTADIR%\mingw\bin;
```

I add the mingw,qt paths 
 Somehow it manages to follow the dynamic lib's path. I don't know where I made the mistake.
Can anybody help me in this issue?.

Note: I am using Windows platform - qt - 4.7.0 (qt - open source v2010.05)of static,dynamic to the Qt-Creater=>Tools=>Options=>Qt.

**EDIT:**
   This one is from the compile output. There is no dynamic path directory mentioned in these.

```
Running build steps for project CalendarNew...
Starting: "D:/TempInstallationFolder/Qt/static/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" clean -w
mingw32-make: Entering directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

D:/TempInstallationFolder/Qt/static/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release clean

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

del release\moc_CalendarWidget.cpp release\moc_DateSquareEditWidget.cpp release\moc_GeneralSettingsWidget.cpp release\moc_MyColorButton.cpp release\moc_MyLabel.cpp

del release\CalendarWidget.o release\DateSquare.o release\DateSquareEditWidget.o   release\GeneralSettingsWidget.o release\main.o release\MyColorButton.o release\MyLabel.o release\moc_CalendarWidget.o release\moc_DateSquareEditWidget.o release\moc_GeneralSettingsWidget.o release\moc_MyColorButton.o release\moc_MyLabel.o

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

D:/TempInstallationFolder/Qt/static/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug clean

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

del debug\moc_CalendarWidget.cpp debug\moc_DateSquareEditWidget.cpp debug\moc_GeneralSettingsWidget.cpp debug\moc_MyColorButton.cpp debug\moc_MyLabel.cpp

del debug\CalendarWidget.o debug\DateSquare.o debug\DateSquareEditWidget.o debug\GeneralSettingsWidget.o debug\main.o debug\MyColorButton.o debug\MyLabel.o debug\moc_CalendarWidget.o debug\moc_DateSquareEditWidget.o debug\moc_GeneralSettingsWidget.o debug\moc_MyColorButton.o debug\moc_MyLabel.o

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

mingw32-make: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

Could Not Find C:\Documents and Settings\prabhakaran\Desktop\CalendarNew-build-desktop\debug\moc_CalendarWidget.cpp

Could Not Find C:\Documents and Settings\prabhakaran\Desktop\CalendarNew-build-desktop\debug\CalendarWidget.o

The process "D:/TempInstallationFolder/Qt/static/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.

Starting: "D:/TempInstallationFolder/Qt/static/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -w

mingw32-make: Entering directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

D:/TempInstallationFolder/Qt/static/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\CalendarWidget.o ..\CalendarNew\CalendarWidget.cpp

..\CalendarNew\CalendarWidget.cpp: In constructor 'CalendarWidget::CalendarWidget()':

..\CalendarNew\CalendarWidget.cpp:93: warning: 'default_String_Fontsize' may be used uninitialized in this function

..\CalendarNew\CalendarWidget.cpp:96: warning: 'lower_String_Fontsize' may be used uninitialized in this function

..\CalendarNew\CalendarWidget.cpp: In constructor 'CalendarWidget::CalendarWidget()':

..\CalendarNew\CalendarWidget.cpp:93: warning: 'default_String_Fontsize' may be used uninitialized in this function

..\CalendarNew\CalendarWidget.cpp:96: warning: 'lower_String_Fontsize' may be used uninitialized in this function

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\DateSquare.o ..\CalendarNew\DateSquare.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\DateSquareEditWidget.o ..\CalendarNew\DateSquareEditWidget.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\GeneralSettingsWidget.o ..\CalendarNew\GeneralSettingsWidget.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\main.o ..\CalendarNew\main.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\MyColorButton.o ..\CalendarNew\MyColorButton.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\MyLabel.o ..\CalendarNew\MyLabel.cpp

D:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 ..\CalendarNew\CalendarWidget.h -o release\moc_CalendarWidget.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\moc_CalendarWidget.o release\moc_CalendarWidget.cpp

D:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 ..\CalendarNew\DateSquareEditWidget.h -o release\moc_DateSquareEditWidget.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\moc_DateSquareEditWidget.o release\moc_DateSquareEditWidget.cpp

D:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 ..\CalendarNew\GeneralSettingsWidget.h -o release\moc_GeneralSettingsWidget.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\moc_GeneralSettingsWidget.o release\moc_GeneralSettingsWidget.cpp

D:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 ..\CalendarNew\MyColorButton.h -o release\moc_MyColorButton.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\moc_MyColorButton.o release\moc_MyColorButton.cpp

D:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 ..\CalendarNew\MyLabel.h -o release\moc_MyLabel.cpp

g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtCore" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\QtGui" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include" -I"..\CalendarNew" -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"." -I"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\moc_MyLabel.o release\moc_MyLabel.cpp

g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release\CalendarNew.exe object_script.CalendarNew.Release  -L"d:\TempInstallationFolder\Qt\static\qt\lib" -lmingw32 -lqtmain -lQtGui4 -lQtCore4 

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

mingw32-make: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/prabhakaran/Desktop/CalendarNew-build-desktop'

The process "D:/TempInstallationFolder/Qt/static/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
```

Note: Now only I made the fresh install for dynamic and static . Still it is capable to produce the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you have built against the static lib? What is your build environment? Do you use qmake or cmake, visual studio, plain nmake makefiles?

Comment: @gnud I am using Qt-Creator. So I didn't make any command line options.

Comment: @Andre Ya,yes. I tried to built against the static lib. I am using Windows-Qt - 4.7.0 . I use qmake.

Comment: That's fine - you can still see your linker flags in the Build Output window when you compile. What's the complete command used to link the final executable?

Comment: Do you perhaps use a 3rdparty lib, which was also built with Qt and is still linked to the (old) dynamic libs? Or perhaps even a component of your own project which was not cleaned correctly?

Comment: please show us the command line passed to the linker!

Comment: @Andre No, I don't use any 3rd party lib. My Project is not that much complex to make the build clean,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this line to your projectname.pro file?

```
CONFIG += static
```

and made sure that in QtCreator-Projects-Build settings the 'Qt-version' points to your static build?

Comment: @Magnus I did all those things. Yes Qt-Version points to my static build. Still I am getting dynamic builds.

Comment: `DEFINES += STATIC`: what purpose should this serve?

Comment: @rubenvb Actually I am not sure :) I just followed these guidelines when I made my static version: [Building static Qt](http://www.formortals.com/build-qt-static-small-microsoft-intel-gcc-compiler/) and [Linking statically to Qt](http://www.formortals.com/how-to-statically-link-qt-4/)

Comment: Well, it really has no meaning, and any use of the `STATIC` string in code will freak out when you do this. I guess it's to disable Windows dllexport directives, if implemented through this `#define`. It's confusing, please remove it from your answer and you'll have my upvote `;)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the correct answer. I made the following changes. I am not sure which one corrected my problem.

1)It seems there must be a environment variable called as QTDIR which points to the dynamic installation dir.

2)I compiled the qt libs for static build using "visual studio" rather than "mingw".

After these steps I added the absolute paths of static and dynamic (qt-bin,lib,minwg-bin,lib) to the path.

Now, my things are working fine. I didn't vote it as a correct answer. Thereby some one can give the exact answer.